# How to change Label text during load?

Tags: asp.net

Im using ASP.NET 4.0.

I have this problem, I cant access the my method in my webform, from outside the page.

This is how it goes.

My webforms instantiate the parseEngine class which in turn instantiate different classes.
Thing is when I have found the text I'm looking for im only halfway through. After that I put everything in the database, and lastly return it.

So I added method to my webform,

```
 Public void Showresult(int myResult)
 {
     Labelt.text = myResult.ToString();
 }
```

But clearly that does not work.

This is how ddep into the application I am

```
Webfrom1 --> ParseEngine --> Parser (HERE),
```

How do I access the control down from the parser?

I also tried making a partial class inside Webform1 and tried to Inherit webform1 there to get access to the label but it wouldn't work.

So what the solution to this, I need this to work so that the user can se the result pretty quick, and then if he/she wants to wait it will render the rest when all database calls are done.

Comment: The parser should not be allowed to change your GUI, otherwise you're hardlinking both. You should use events to communicate between your page and the parser. You could create a custom `parserFinished` event which you can handle from the page. Then you can use the argument which can be the parser itself or the parser-result to show it on the page.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that!?!?! I have everything I need to do that, I built it that way.. -_-  Thanks!